# MySQL - Restrição Foreign Key entre tabelas

Tags: mysql

Abaixo criei 4 tabelas fictícias para ilustração

[image: ilustração]
As tabelas Professor e Aluno são referenciadas por Endereço e Documentos. Porém, como eu posso criar uma chave estrangeira nas duas últimas tabelas que referencie Professor OU Aluno? Se eu criar uma chave pra cada, o banco pode ficar inconsistente? Há outro jeito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duas alternativas:

1 - 
Cria-se mais uma tabela TB_PESSOA com id,id_endereço e id_documento

TB_ALUNO e TB_PROFESSOR recebem o campo id_pessoa

Fica mais fácil caso você queira criar um terceiro tipo de usuário, além de ficar mais fácil de converter para lógica de programação orientada objeto

2 -
**Cria-se mais uma tabela TB_PESSOA, e move todos os campos de TB_ENDEREÇO e TB_DOCUMENTO para TB_PESSOA e torná-los opcional**. Fica menos fragmentado e mais fácil de gerenciar.

Comment: Nem pensei nisso haha vou implementar e volto pra marcar a resposta